# Applescript: Moving a file using only it's path

Tags: path, applescript, directory, file-move

Thanks to help from people on Stack Overflow, I'm working on a huge program using **Applescript**, but I have gotten stuck at a part where I have made a **new folder**, and I am trying to **move 2 illustrator files into it**. Normally this wouldn't be a problem as I have moved file before after selected them with "choose", but this time I'm not selecting them **I only have variables with their full paths.**

**So my question is how can I move the 2 files using their full paths?**
Can I somehow manipulate the variables into a more manageable format?

This is the part of the code not working (the full thing is huge but I can post it if requested) and a few snippets of where variables got their values from

```
 set saveLocation to ((path to desktop) as string) --place to save the files
 set theFile to choose file --choose .ai file to get outlines on
tell application "Finder" to set fileName to name of theFile
set fullPath to (saveLocation & fileName) --file path of new .ai

make new folder at saveLocation with properties {name:(text 1 thru ((length of fileName) - 3) of fileName)}
tell current application
    set newFolder to POSIX path of saveLocation
    set newFolder to newFolder & (text 1 thru ((length of fileName) - 3) of fileName)

*--set newFolder to choose folder* -- I tested to see if manually selecting the new folder helped, it didn't

 move fullPath to newFolder
```

I really appreciate any help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, set the make folder to a variable to call later. Looks like this:

```
tell app "finder" --need to use Finder to move files
    set somevariable to make new folder at saveLocation with properties {name:(text 1 thru ((length of fileName) - 3) of fileName)}
    move file fullPath to folder somevariable
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks very much :) I should have been able to figure this out myself but I was pretty brain dead at the time :p